# Get highest score of a user in current week Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I have a table 'score' with following values

```
id  user_id score   created_at            updated_at
43  33      88      2020-02-23 00:00:00     NULL
44  33      89      2020-02-24 00:00:00     NULL
45  33      42      2020-02-24 00:00:00     NULL
46  33      86      2020-02-25 00:00:00     NULL
47  33      100     2020-02-04 00:00:00     NULL
```

I am trying to print highest score of a particular user on current week. I am using the following code.

```
            $week = GameScore::whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('score','desc')
            ->limit(1)
            ->first();
```

When I run the above code I am getting 86 as the result.

```
  "result": {
    "id": 46,
    "user_id": 33,
    "score": 86,
    "created_at": "2020-02-24 18:30:00",    //this date is not correct for score 86 as per the table
    "updated_at": null
   }
```

But if I run the same query in mysql I am getting 89 and according to my requirement 89 should be the answer, because 89 is the highest score of the user in this week till now.

mySql query I run for the above code

```
   select * from `scores` where date(`created_at`) >= '2020-02-24 00:00:00' and date(`created_at`) <= '2020-03-01 23:59:59' and `user_id` = 33 order by `score` desc limit 1
```

Comment: can u post your same mysql query?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Apart from the given answers, I also recommend checking out `Laravel Collection max()` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-max

Comment: try `dd(Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`,  and see what it is.

Comment: @TsaiKoga it gives me "2020-02-24 00:00:00"

Comment: if score is 89, created_at is `2020-02-24 00:00:00`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga  yes for score 89 date is 2020-02-24 00:00:00

Comment: Updated my question with the response I got after running code.

Comment: try  between `date_field BETWEEN '2020-02-24 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-01 23:59:59'`

Comment: @sh1hab I used whereBetween but still I get 86

Comment: 86 created_at is  2020-02-24 18:30:00, make sure 89's created_at greater than 2020-02-24

Comment: @TsaiKoga in my table for score 86 created_at is 2020-02-25 00:00:00 and for 89 created_at is 2020-02-24 00:00:00

Comment: Date() appears counterproductive in this instance

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your query with `Laravel` eloquent's `->max('')` function. It takes a column name as its argument.

Your query should look like the following:

```
$week = GameScore::whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->max('score');
```

Comment: it still gives me 86.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()` aggregate function. Try,

```
 $week = GameScore::whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->max('score');
```

For more details check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates

Comment: still this gives me 86

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the timezone. You can try to use the mysql timezone for Carbon:

```php
->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->tz('xxx')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

Or change the config/app.php

```php
'timezone' => 'xxx'; // change to the same as mysql
```

Comment: Changing whereDate to where and format to Y-m-d gives me 86 itself. According to my table I need 89 .

Comment: @Oops don't change both, just choose one.

Comment: yes, as you said I first changed both whereDate to where and after running I got 86. Then I redo all and changed the format to Y-m-d and that too gave me 86